# Extract zip files and recompress them into 7zip files

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip, archiving

I'd like my zip files to be extracted, then recompressed into 7zip files.

## Example:

### Before:

```
$ ls
001.zip
002.zip
003.zip
--snip--
997.zip
998.zip
999.zip
```

### After:

```
$ ls
001.7z
002.7z
003.7z
--snip--
997.7z
998.7z
999.7z
```

I've tried doing this with GUI programs, but I can't bulk compress files into seperate archives.

### Speed

Some of my folders have up to 17,000 zips in them, which I need to recompress into 7z. So speed is preferable

Comment: This is basically the same question but in the opposite direction:  [Repack 7z files to zip files in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1115548/repack-7z-files-to-zip-files-in-linux)

Comment: @satwell Thrid solution worked perfectly, thank you